# saving and returing listbox content C#

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, ini, streamwriter

I have a question about saving content from a listbox and putting it in a .ini file.  
 Also i want to retrieve the information and put it back in the listbox when the programm starts.  
I have two listboxes lets call them `listBox1` and `listBox2`.  
And 1 button lets call that `selectbttn`.  
The content from `listBox2` must be saved when i click on the select button.  ,br />
How can i fix this?

This is the code with the 2 listboxes, id ont have a code for the select button.
The button that you see in the code is a add button that adds content from listbox1 to listbox 2.

```
   private void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (list_selected.Items.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not add the type twice.");
            }
            else
            {
                list_selected.Items.Add(List_selection.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

            {
                MessageBox.Show("No type selected");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing to fix, you just haven't attempted this **at all**. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `StreamWriter` to save to the file.  You could do something like the following:

```
public void SaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\YourFile.ini"))
   {
       foreach (var item in list_selected.Items)
       {
         file.WriteLine(item.ToString());
       }
   }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx

You can use a `StreamReader` to read back the contents of the .ini file when your application loads.  I will leave this to you since you did not originally provide code.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
File.WriteAllLines("test.ini", 
                listbox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToArray());
```

Load

```
 listbox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("test.ini")
                   .Select(l => new ListItem(l)).ToArray());
```